# Check if checkbox ever had value 1

Tags: php, yii2

I have a Checkbox where it is important that only the first click triggers an action. In another function,

```
if($checkboxModel->value==1 && $checkboxModel->oldAttributes['value']==0)
```

is called.

Is there any way to test if the checkbox was ever clicked before? As I understand it, oldAttributes is just the most recent value before the current, right?

Comment: the first click of what and for what? of a checkbox? on the whole session?... Please, be more descriptive, otherwise, I don't see how can we help you.

Comment: First click ever. If the individual checkbox has ever been clicked before by anyone at any time since it's creation, it should not execute anything anymore.

Comment: Then you might store that in some persistence place (DB, file...), no? Otherwise, how do you expect to know that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `oldAttributes` property are used to store attribute values that were loaded from DB or last values that were stored in DB.

Let's say that you have record like this in DB:

```
id | value
----------
1  |  0
```

Then the `oldAttributes` property will work like this:

```php
$model = MyModel::findOne(1);
echo $model->value; //output 0
echo $model->oldAttributes['value']; //output 0

$model->value = 1;
echo $model->value; //output 1
echo $model->oldAttributes['value']; //output 0

$model->value = 2;
echo $model->value; //output 2
echo $model->oldAttributes['value']; //output 0

$model->save();
echo $model->value; //output 2
echo $model->oldAttributes['value']; //output 2

$model->value = 1;
echo $model->value; //output 1
echo $model->oldAttributes['value']; //output 2
```

The `oldAttributes` property doesn't remember the values the record had in some different request.

If you want to determine whether the action was already executed you need to add some extra field to the DB where you will store that information. When executing the action you will change the value of that extra field. When the checkbox state is changed you will check the extra attribute to see whether the action has already been executed or it should be executed now.

The DB table might look like this:

```
id | value | action_executed
----------------------------
1  |   0   |       0
```

And the check in your code:

```php
if(
    $checkboxModel->value==1 
    && $checkboxModel->oldAttributes['value']==0
    && $checkboxModel->action_executed == 0
) {
    // ... execute action
    // update action_executed field
    $checkboxModel->action_executed = 1;
    $checkboxModel->save(false, ['action_executed']);
   //false to turn of validation and the second param to save only that attribute
}
```